# Having trouble to install Raspbian(Could not expand file system)

Tags: raspbian

I'm using SanDisk Ultra 64GB and i'm using Etcher to flash it and it says that it's successfully finished but it split up into 2 drives, one of them is renamed to boot which i can access but the other one when i click on my PC says that i need to format it if i want to use it, which i don't. I plugged it into my TV with HDMI cable and it pops an error that says `Could not expand filesystem, please try raspi-config or rc_gui. Boot and root partitions are on different devices` .

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and the manufacturer is Element14

Comment: You must have done something after writing the image. Just re-image the Card and put it in the Pi without fiddling with it.

Comment: @Milliways Once i have flashed it i put it on the raspberry pi

Comment: "Boot and root partitions are on different devices" - that's odd, what's the output of `mount -l|grep mmcblk`

Comment: Add output of `findmnt /boot` and `findmnt /` to your question. Also mention any other storage devices connected.

Comment: If you are running **Etcher** on Windows this is a normal behavior since Windows cant read Linux file systems natively.

Answer (score 2):

When you flash the Raspbian image,  you should get 2 partitions on the  SD card.

The error suggests expanding the fs with the raspi-config configuration tool, as this is a usual setup step in setting up a new Raspbian install, as it will write on the disk, but won't utilise the remainder free space, until it is expanded.

Download a fresh, latest install of Raspbian that is suited for your type of Raspberry Pi, Flash it to the SD card,  I use ApplePiBaker on my Mac, but there are other alternatives.

Insert the SD into the Pi and boot to a TV HDMI like you are doing now.

Once in, you should be able to log into the Pi using it's default user / password...

Open Terminal, if you are not in the command line already, and type:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

to enter the config interface,

Select Advanced Options (#7) and the top entry to Expand Filesystem.

This will briefly allocate the rest of the freespace on the SD to be available by the system.

Hope this helps.